# iOS -navigate from AppDelegate to FrontViewController of SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I try navigate to FrontViewController of SWRevealViewController from AppDelegate

In AppDelegate.m

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 Home_tableView *home =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home_view"];
[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:home animated:NO];
```

when it load my Home_tableView.m in viewDidLoad method,I got `self.revealViewController` is `nil` & its crash

```
 SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
 _nav_bar.target = self.revealViewController;
 _nav_bar.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

My storyboard like this [image]

Comment: in your screen shot no **Home_tableView** view controller, then which view controller identifier name is **home_view**

Comment: what is revealViewController identifier in storyboard ?

Comment: I wasnt assign one but I make one now called "reveal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try like this may be help you.

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    UIViewController* vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"revealidentifier"];
```

Now use **vc** as your revealViewController.

NOTE: **You have to enable navigationcontroll "FirstViewController"**

Comment: how can I use vc as revealviewcontroller

Comment: you have to pass revealViewController identifire [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"revealidentifier"]

Comment: you have to enable navigation from "FrontViewController"

Comment: FrontViewController have navigation Controller , what you mean by enable it ??

Comment: what is your rootviewcontroller ?

Comment: First view Controller is my root view, Hometable is front view of swrevealviewcontroller

Comment: so You have to enable navigationcontroll "FirstViewController"

Comment: I did now Embed in -> Navigation Controller , but its still the same

Comment: where you assign memory to self.revealViewController?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using SWRevealViewController which is on Github
and you can follow this tutorial to integrate it into your app.
this is really amazing tutorial and it will help you

```
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @Dipen Chudasama I get the answer 
in my AppDelegate.m file , I put this code to navigate to my slide menu (SWRevealViewController)

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    SWRevealViewController *home = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"reveal"];

   [self.window  makeKeyAndVisible];
   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:home animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Thank you for every one try to help me

Comment: Thank you , I have anther little problem , how to access any item in my slidemenu , I can Access Default one but cant access the others Any idea

Comment: not able to understand what exactly you want ? Describe or post one more question...so clear this.

Comment: I add Question now have a look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067352/ios-navigate-from-appdelegate-to-certain-item-in-slidemenu