# iOS- navigate From AppDelegate to certain item in slidemenu

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I use swrevealviewcontroller to add slide menu to my app ,

[image]

Let consider we have menu like this one in pic 
I need navigate from My appDelegate to any item in menu (ex:Map View Controller )

my tries :

in my appDelegate.m

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    InforView *school_view = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"info_view"];

   [self.window  makeKeyAndVisible];

   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:school_view animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

When its move to InforView Controller it crash in viewdidload

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _nav_bar.target = self.revealViewController;
    _nav_bar.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

 // its crash here 
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
```

> my storyboard

navigation controller --> home view --> reveal View controller

reveal View controller has two views --> slide menu
navigation controller -- > Front view

my slide menu has some items as appear in pic

I need navigate from my appDelegate to one of this items

[image]

Comment: put breakpoint at there...and make sure that self.revealViewController is not nil...

Comment: self.revealViewController is nil

Comment: yes thats why it crash...

Comment: I know but how can I fix it

Comment: I think I think access it throw my SWRevealViewController then navigate to slidemenu item

Comment: the sliding menu is "self.revealViewController" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69297/discussion-between-dipen-chudasama-and-mina-fawzy).

Comment: Maybe you can try: 
self.window.rootViewController = school_view;
[self.window  makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: Not yet , could you give me suggestion

Comment: You need to assign `self.revealViewController` with it's actual value. Also why are you navigating from AppDelegate ?

Comment: I get notification , so I want navigate to right place to open this notification , can you please add some code to me

Comment: @minafawzy: Can't you just listen for notification from the SWRevealController class ? Instead of AppDelegate ?

Comment: notification has three condition , one if app is inactive , active or application closed , can I handle all that outside AppDelegate

Comment: @minafawzy yes you can :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification

Comment: @EdAbe my problem with library , we i navigate to one of my slide menu items its crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I find the answer

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    // this any item in list you want navigate to 
Home_tableView *home = (Home_tableView *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home_view"];

SlideMenu *slidemenu = (SlideMenu *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu_view"];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:home];

UINavigationController *smVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:slidemenu];

// define rear and frontviewcontroller  
SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]initWithRearViewController:smVC frontViewController:nav];

// make it as root 
self.window.rootViewController = revealController;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SidebarDemo project, you can use the following code to show MapViewController on initial loading.

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = (SWRevealViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MapViewController *mapVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapID"];

[self.window  makeKeyAndVisible];

UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)revealViewController.frontViewController;
[navController setViewControllers: @[mapVC] animated: NO ];
[revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```

After `makeKeyAndVisible`, the frontViewController and realViewController of the revealViewController are loaded. And you can set rootViewController of frontViewController, which is a navigationController.

Comment: Thank you for answer , but this code is crash I got this error libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you show where the error occurs and the exception stack trace?

Comment: The error occurs here  UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)revealViewController.frontViewController;  error stack Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController frontViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17542050'

Comment: Is revealViewController in your code a type of SWRevealViewController?

Comment: revealViewController is the rootviewcontroller of the storyboard, looks like your root view controller is a navigation controller, not SWRevealViewController, if it is, try (UINavigationController *)[revealViewController frontViewController].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70694/discussion-between-mina-fawzy-and-gabbler).